# On Button1_Click need to get value from selected DataKey (User presses Select in gridview and highlights row)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is kiling me.  On Button1_Click I need to get the value from selected DataKey (User presses Select in gridview and highlights row)..Can anyone help? Thank You..

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {      
    string id = GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString(); 
    Label1.Text = id;
   }
```

Comment: are you using the vanilla asp.net server control or are you using a custom gridview control from a third-party?

Comment: vanilla, no sugar...straight out of the box..

Comment: that's too bad. If you were using Telerik I could tell you how in a heartbeat :)

Comment: Have you provided the GridView's [DataKeyNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx)?

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have? Did you set the DataKeyNames property on the grid?

Comment: I did set the DataKeyName, Keeps returning 0...Does the code work for you? DataKeyNames="RegistrationID"

Comment: Nice question. I am also searching solution 
for the same condition.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what's not working, do you get any errors?

To retrieve the SelectedDataKey you have to tell the GridView what's the primary key column of your datasource via it's property [DataKeyNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx).
You could also use the GridView's [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedvalue.aspx) property.

If all does not work, you should provide source code. Maybe you are binding the GridView on every postback.

Comment: I am checking for postback on the databind(). This will work for a field in gridview but does not work when visible = false Label1.Text = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex].Cells[0].Text;

Comment: @Chris: ...and the aspx part?

Comment: Ok not sure what happened just closed out my solution and did a rebuild.. Code above works for anyone looking for this..